# parsing vmstat python code explained

Tags: python, parsing

I found some python code to parse the output of the linux command 'vmstat' below.

```
vmstat | python -c 'import sys; print dict(zip(*map(str.split, sys.stdin)[-2:])).get("cache")'

vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
11  0 385372 101696  61704 650716    0    1     5     9    6   12  5  2 92  0
```

I was wondering if somebody could explain to me what the code is doing particularly the (zip(*map(str.split, sys.stdin)[-2:]) part?

Thank you

Comment: you should break down each step and see what each returns

Comment: i would have chosen awk to avoid all these ambiguous oneliners: `vmstat | awk '{print $6}'`.

Answer (score 3):

That's some clever code, but a bit too clever.

Let's decompose :
    dict(zip(*map(str.split, sys.stdin)[-2:]))

The first operation is going to be:
    map(str.split, sys.stdin)

Map apply the function given as its first parameter to each element of the iterable of its second parameter. (If the second parameter is not an iterable, it will be casted as one to give an iterable result).
E.g., here :

```
>>> map (int, ["1", "2", "3"])
[1, 2, 3]

>>> (int, "1")
[1]
```

So here, this first expression can be read as : "apply str.split on the standard input" (sys.stdin).

The result of this first operation is easy to examine:

```
vmstat | python -c 'import sys; print (map(str.split, sys.stdin))'

[['procs', '-----------memory----------', '---swap--', '-----io----', '-system--', '----cpu----'], ['r', 'b', 'swpd', 'free', 'buff', 'cache', 'si', 'so', 'bi', 'bo', 'in', 'cs', 'us', 'sy', 'id', 'wa'], ['1', '0', '490952', '155924', '437356', '2064528', '0', '0', '3', '59', '0', '1', '6', '1', '91', '2']]
```

The standard input was an array of 3 lines. Each line was split with the default split operation, so each element is nicely parsed. Now, we don't need the first line, so we want only the two last line of the array, hence the [-2:]. Once again, this is classic python :

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[-2:]
[3,4]
```

So we have a list of list of size 2. The first list is the line with the keys, the second list is the line with corresponding values. This looks like a dictionary, doesn't it ? But it's not one yet. We need dict, for this.
Dict is a type which has a few constructors, one of those being :

```
 help(dict)
 [...]
 |  dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
 |      (key, value) pairs
 [...]
```

So that if I input :

```
 dict([('name', 'john'), ('profession', 'computer scientist')])
```

I get:

```
 {'name': 'john', 'profession': 'computer scientist'}
```

But we do not have a list of tuples [(key, value)], we have a list of lists [[key, key, key...], [value, value, value...]].

One way of getting a list of tuples is to use the zip function.

```
>>> k = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
>>> v = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
>>> zip(k,v)
[('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3')]
```

And the result of zip is something we can use to build a dict !
But we do not have two separate iterators k and v, here. We only have a list of lists ! So there is another trick at play here : passing arguments as a list. This is documented here :
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

The idea is that if you have a function that takes x arguments, you can give them explicitely, like this :

```
def fun(a,b):
   return a + b

fun(2,3)
```

But you can also call them with a list, using the * syntax, like this :

```
fun(*[2,3])
```

The "*" sign means : "Unpack everything from the list to each argument". Note that if I do :

```
fun(*[2,3,4])
```

It will fail, just as if I tried :

```
fun(2,3,4)
```

Because fun only wants 2 arguments. So here, our list [[key, key...], [value, value]] will be given to zip unpacked, so the real call is zip([key, key...], [value, value...])... which give us exacty what we want, a dictionary. On this dictionary, we simply get the value with the key "cache". And we're done.

This one-liner is clever, but not pleasant to read, though. HuStmpHrrr provides a much better way of doing this in the comment under the question.

Comment: Thank you Raveline for your very detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you Raveline for an amazing explanation. Do you know where I can find the HuStmpHrrr tutorials regarding this ? tried to look through.
Didn't find it on the web

Comment: Many thanks! But I don't see a comment from HuStmpHrrr. Was it deleted or something?